# The best Code Contracts alternative for VS 2017/2019 and .net core projects?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, code-analysis, static-analysis

I was using [Code Contracts](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts) in several projects and I was really satisfied with its static checker and propagated it across other developers.
With new Visual Studio 2017 and .NET Core projects, I found two major drawbacks, which got me to look for an alternative. The first drawback is that Code Contracts aren't supported in Visual Studio 2017 and later versions, although there is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767941/does-vs2017-work-with-codecontracts) for the static checker. The second drawback is that Code Contracts don't support .NET Core projects.

I would like to use static checking in my current projects (some of them are .NET Core based, others not) and I am looking for an alternative. One of the possible alternatives is [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody), but I don't have any experience with this IL assembly modifier.

Do you know about any better alternative tool for static checking?

Comment: Although there doesn't seem to be a concrete alternative at the moment, you would want to read [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23869#issuecomment-415670905) comment, and also vote and take part in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/105) discussion.